# Combine files from terminal

Tags: terminal

I created two files

```
$ 'test' > test.md
$ 'hello' > hello.md
```

try to combine them

```
cat test.md hello.md > combined.md
```

Unfortunately, the newly combined.md is blank.

How to combine files from terminal with commands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to 'echo` your words into the files.

```
echo test >test.md
echo hello >hello.md
cat test.md hello.md >combined.md
```